# Errors while variable arithmetic in configuration file

Tags: omnet++

I want to calculate an ini variable depending on a different variable and a number, but I can't get it to work. I tried different versions of the following code - with and without brackets around the term:

```
warmup-period = ${warmup = 0}s
sim-time-limit = ${stime = ${warmup} + 2400}s
```

OMNeT++ always gives me this error:

> Error: Could not read option sim-time-limit= from the
>   configuration: Syntax error parsing quantity '0 + 2400s': Garbage
>   after first number

I also tried using `($warmup)` instead of `${warump}` as suggested by the [manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:referencing-other-iteration-variables), but this gives me the following error:

> Error: Could not read option sim-time-limit= from the
>   configuration: Syntax error parsing quantity '(0) + 2400s': Must begin
>   with a number

I am using OMNeT++ version 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to use an INI variable for `sim-time-limit`, because the simulation environment expects **only** a number (with unit). Here is the line from `src\envir\envirbase.cc` which reads the value of `sim-time-limit`:

```
opt->simtimeLimit = cfg->getAsDouble(CFGID_SIM_TIME_LIMIT, -1);
```

Comment: Well, this is not 100% correct. At least `sim-time-limit = ${stime = 2400}s` works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, it seems that `sim-time-limit` is read slightly different than "usual" variables.

Comment: Amendment: Also the naming `stime` does not work, meaning it is not recorded as iteration var. Thus, you were right.