# How to get the sim-time-limit from result files?

Tags: omnet++

Apparently, OMNeT++ (i.e. version 5.1) does write every parameter and attribute into the result files, except for `sim-time-limit`. I checked `.sca`, `.vec` and `.vci` files for it, but it is not included.

I was able to write the `warmup-period` into the files by making it a named iteration variable <strike>but this does not work for `sim-time-limit` (see [Errors while variable arithmetic in configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501200/errors-while-variable-arithmetic-in-configuration-file))</strike>.

Is there any possibility to get this value written into the result files? I coulnd't find anything in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully recorded it by defining it as an iteration variable

```
sim-time-limit = ${timelimit= 90min}
```

This will write out

```
itervar timelimit 90min
```

in the .sca file.

Comment: Which version did you use? For me it is 5.1.

Comment: Tested both on 5.4.1 and 5.1. On 5.1 it is written out as an attribute: attr limit 90min, but it's still available.

Comment: Worked. Apparently, I made a mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get `sim-time-limit` as a double value at the runtime:

```
cConfigOption simTimeConfig("sim-time-limit", true,cConfigOption::Type::CFG_DOUBLE, "s", "300", "");

double maxSimTime = cSimulation::getActiveSimulation()->getEnvir()->getConfig()->getAsDouble(&simTimeConfig);
```

Source:
https://syntaxsugar.de/posts/omnetpp-reading-parameters/